# Getting invalid value from TextBox in GridView on button Click event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I have a `GridView gvInvoice` in `<ItemTemplate>` of this I have taken a `Panel` which contains another `GridView gvInvoiceDetails` in it as mentioned in the code below.

**ASPX code**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvInvoice"
              runat="server"
              AutoGenerateColumns="false"
              CssClass="Grid"
              ShowFooter="true"
              OnPageIndexChanging="gvInvoice_PageIndexChanging"
              OnRowEditing="gvInvoice_RowEditing"
              OnRowDeleting="gvInvoice_RowDeleting"
              OnRowCancelingEdit="gvInvoice_RowCancelingEdit"
              OnRowUpdating="gvInvoice_RowUpdating"
              DataKeyNames="Invoice_Description_Id"
              OnRowDataBound="gvInvoice_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img alt=""
                     style="cursor: pointer"
                     src="Images/plus.png" />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders"
                           runat="server"
                           Style="display: none">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvInvoiceDetails"
                                  runat="server"
                                  AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                  ShowFooter="true"
                                  CssClass="ChildGrid"
                                  OnRowCommand="gvInvoiceDetails_RowCommand"
                                  OnRowDataBound="gvInvoiceDetails_RowDataBound"
                                  OnPageIndexChanging="gvInvoiceDetails_PageIndexChanging"
                                  OnRowEditing="gvInvoiceDetails_RowEditing"
                                  OnRowDeleting="gvInvoiceDetails_RowDeleting"
                                  OnRowCancelingEdit="gvInvoiceDetails_RowCancelingEdit"
                                  OnRowUpdating="gvInvoiceDetails_RowUpdating"
                                  DataKeyNames="Invoice_Detail_Id">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description"
                                               ItemStyle-Width="150px">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescription"
                                               runat="server"
                                               Text='<%#Eval("Invoice_Detail")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditDetailDescription"
                                                 TextMode="MultiLine"
                                                 runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddDetailDescription"
                                                 TextMode="MultiLine"
                                                 runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate"
                                               ItemStyle-Width="150px">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblRate"
                                               runat="server"
                                               Text='<%#Eval("Invoice_Rate")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditDetailRate"
                                                 runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddDetailRate"
                                                 runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount"
                                               ItemStyle-Width="150px">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblAmount"
                                               runat="server"
                                               Text='<%#Eval("Invoice_Amount")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditDetailAmount"
                                                 runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddDetailAmount"
                                                 runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate"
                                                CommandName="Update"
                                                runat="server"
                                                Text="Update" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel"
                                                CommandName="Cancel"
                                                runat="server"
                                                Text="Cancel" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit"
                                                CommandName="Edit"
                                                runat="server"
                                                Text="Edit" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete"
                                                CommandName="Delete"
                                                runat="server"
                                                Text="Delete"
                                                OnClientClick="return DeleteConfirmation()" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddInvoiceDetails"
                                                CommandName="Add"
                                                OnClick="btnAddInvoiceDetails_Click"
                                                runat="server"
                                                Text="Add" />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description"
                           ItemStyle-Width="577px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDescription"
                           runat="server"
                           Text='<%#Eval("Invoice_Description")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditDescription"
                             runat="server"
                             TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFooterDescription"
                             runat="server"
                             TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount"
                           ItemStyle-Width="450px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblInvoiceAmount"
                           runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEditamount"
                           runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFooterAmount"
                           runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate"
                            CommandName="Update"
                            runat="server"
                            Text="Update" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel"
                            CommandName="Cancel"
                            runat="server"
                            Text="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnEdit"
                            CommandName="Edit"
                            runat="server"
                            Text="Edit" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnDelete"
                            CommandName="Delete"
                            runat="server"
                            Text="Delete"
                            OnClientClick="return DeleteConfirmation()" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddEName"
                            OnClick="btnAddEName_Click"
                            runat="server"
                            Text="Add" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My problem is when I am trying to fetch value from `txtAddDetailDescription` `txtAddDetailRate` & `txtAddDetailAmount` on button click event `btnAddInvoiceDetails_Click` I get `,` before all three values and I am no able to find from where I am getting this `,` I tried searching may be I have placed `,` in code but not able to find any. So if anyone can help finding from where I am getting this `,` will be very helpful. My `.cs` code is as follows.

**CS code**

```
protected void btnAddInvoiceDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow gvInvoiceDetailsRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    GridView gvInvoiceDetails = (GridView)gvInvoiceDetailsRow.NamingContainer;
    TextBox Description = ((TextBox)gvInvoiceDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddDetailDescription"));
    TextBox DetailRate = ((TextBox)gvInvoiceDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddDetailRate"));
    TextBox DetailAmount = ((TextBox)gvInvoiceDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddDetailAmount"));
    GridViewRow gvInvoiceRow = (GridViewRow)gvInvoiceDetails.NamingContainer;
    GridView gvInvoice = (GridView)gvInvoiceRow.NamingContainer;
    string RequestId = Convert.ToString(gvInvoice.DataKeys[gvInvoiceRow.RowIndex].Value);
    int Invoice_Description_Id = Convert.ToInt16(RequestId);
    SqlParameter[] spa = new SqlParameter[5];
    spa[0] = new SqlParameter("@Type", 2);
    spa[1] = new SqlParameter("@Invoice_Detail", Description.Text);
    spa[2] = new SqlParameter("@Invoice_Rate", Convert.ToDecimal(DetailRate.Text));
    spa[3] = new SqlParameter("@Invoice_Amount", Convert.ToDecimal(DetailAmount.Text));
    spa[4] = new SqlParameter("@Invoice_Description_Id", Invoice_Description_Id);
    int k = gs.Sp_InsertUpdateDelete("Sp_Invoice_Detail", spa);
    if (k > 0)
    {
        Response.Write("Record Inserted successfully");
        FillDetailGrid(gvInvoiceDetails, Invoice_Description_Id);
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
            $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
            $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
        });
        $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "Images/plus.png");
            $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you please post 'Sp_Invoice_Detail' stored procedure?

Comment: @staticvoidmain problem is not with stored procedure because value is getting fetched before even Stored Procedure is executed

Comment: The above c# .cs file you have pasted I hope is for insert/update but your problem happens during retrieve/fetch.  Could you please check the data in the table or the select query if it has an extra ','?

Comment: Are you getting text value as `,`?

Comment: @staticvoidmain yes the above code is for insert/update and I am fetching data from `txtAddDetailDescription` `txtAddDetailRate` & `txtAddDetailAmount` not from any Table in Database

Comment: @Bharadwaj yes I am getting text value with `,` along with actual value For eg:- If I type `abc` in `txtAddDetailDescription` and when I fetch value on `click event` as mentioned in above code I get `,abc` instead of `abc`

Comment: After button click, are you seeing `,` value in the text box? I mean in ui?

Comment: @Bharadwaj yes even In UI I am getting `,` on button click

Comment: Then it is something related to the `javascript` or `jquery` which is triggering to add `,` into your text box.

Comment: @Bharadwaj I have added `JavaScript` in the question can you please have a look  and check if there a anything I am doing wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95524/discussion-between-navy-and-bharadwaj).